# Which are you currently using for XF authentication and why, Firebase or Appcenter?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Did anyone look into these and find any specific problems with either one?

I'm just at the start of evaluating both and so wondering what problems there might be with one or the other that would exclude either.

Which are you using and why?

Comment: Speaking from personal experience, it's a lot harder to maintain and integrate Firebase into Xamarin since they don't have documentation that supports Xamarin. I had to find outdated blogs that supports this feature. The documentation on Firebase only supports native iOS and native Android or Web. On the other hand, Microsoft created both App Center and Xamarin so integration with these two is a lot smoother in my experience.